# renderAllRows: false still renders all rows

Tags: html, render, handsontable

I am creating a table and have renderAllRows:false and it still renders all rows, giving me the 'performance tip:

*VM6606 handsontable.full.min.js:61 Performance tip: Handsontable rendered more than 1000 visible rows. Consider limiting the number of rendered rows by specifying the table height and/or turning off the "renderAllRows" option.
*
I don't know why it isn't working, and being a newbie at HOT, I don't know if placement is a problem, or some other issue.  Any help appreciated.

My data set has 18k rows, so I would LOVE to disable it, but it doesn't seem to work.

any ideas why it doesn't work?  Additionally, the readonly:true doesn't work either.

Here's the code:

```
 HOT_prg_grp = new Handsontable(HOTcontainer, {
      data: data_bucket,
      renderAllRows: false,
      columns: [{ type: 'text', readonly:true }, 
                { type: 'text', readonly:false }],
      colHeaders: ["Program", "Group"] ,
      afterChange: (changed) => {
        changed?.forEach(([row, col, oldValue, newValue]) => {
          var prg = HOT_prg_grp.getDataAtCell(row, 0);
          chg = [prg, newValue];
          changes.push(chg);
        });
      },
      licenseKey :'blah blah' 
    });
  }
```

I would expect the 'renderAllRows: false to work.  also, renderAllRows: False fails.

Comment: Well as far as the readonly .. You are setting it to false, then setting it to true right below it ..

Comment: `renderAllRows` is `false` by default. You could try to set up `viewportRowRenderingOffset` and `viewportColumnRenderingOffset`, and follow tips listed in the performance tutorial https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/performance/

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to do much either.  Performance was improved by being more selective in what records are to be included.